# Composer dump-autoload gives preg_match error

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have Composer in my PHP project installed, and want to use the autoloader. On [this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) page I read how the `composer.json` file should look like and that I should run the command `dump-autoload`. My `composer.json` file looks as follows

```
{
    "require-dev":{
        "phpunit/phpunit":"4.5.*",
        "autoload":{
            "psr-0":{
                "Yii\\":"yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run from the terminal `php composer.phar dump-autoload`, I get the following error message.

[image: Error message Composer]

1. What second parameter and what array is it talking about?
2. How can I solve this issue to generate a new `autoload.php` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autoload` should be moved out of `require-dev`:

```
{
    "require-dev":{
        "phpunit/phpunit":"4.5.*"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-0":{
            "Yii\\":"yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/"
        }
    }
}
```

You can test your composer.json file using `composer validate`. Your original file returned:

```
./composer.json is invalid, the following errors/warnings were found:
require-dev.autoload : invalid value, must be a string containing a version constraint
the property name is required
the property description is required
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your composer.json file is not correct.

`require-dev` and `autoload` are 2 main sections.

This should work:

```
{
    "require-dev":{
        "phpunit/phpunit":"4.5.*"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-0":{
            "Yii\\":"yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/"
        }
    }
}
```